# KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 300.0 secs

Tags: python, apache-kafka, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Kafka-Python for a very basic way of streaming some data by setting up a KafkaProducer and a KafkaConsumer in two jupyter notebooks, similar to this article: https://dorianbg.wordpress.com/2017/11/11/ingesting-realtime-tweets-using-apache-kafka-tweepy-and-python/

Setting up my producer:

```
import time
!pip install kafka-python
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], api_version=(0, 10, 1), max_block_ms = 300000, api_version_auto_timeout_ms=300000)
topic_name = 'test'


def send_data(interval):

    while True: 
        producer.send(topic_name, str(1))
        time.sleep(interval)
```

Setting up my consumer:

```
!pip install kafka-python
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092",
                        group_id = "random",
                        api_version=(0, 10, 1), consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
consumer.subscribe('test')

for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

When I run these in separate notebooks, I get the following message in the producer-notebook:

> KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after
>   300.0 secs.

I'm well aware that this is a question that has been asked previously ([KafkaTimeoutError('Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275952/kafkatimeouterrorfailed-to-update-metadata-after-60-0-secs), https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/721, etc.) but these situations differ from mine, or the answers provided do not resolve my issues.

Thanks!

Comment: have the `test` topic been created on your local host?

Comment: Yes, I have @yuyang