# How to resolve KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kafka-python, aws-msk

I'm trying to send messages using kafka-python to my AWS MSK Serverless cluster.
I've created MSK Serverless cluster by following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-serverless-produce-consume.html

My cluster is in active state and I have an EC2 instance in the same VPC and with the same subnet as my cluster. I've created a topic an successfully sent and red messages to it and from it by using the command line (Step 5 in the tutorial).

Now I need to do the same using python. So I tried to do the following:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
cluster_endpoint = 'boot-name.c1.kafka-serverless.reagion-name.amazonaws.com:9098'
producer = KafkaProducer(security_protocol="SSL",bootstrap_servers=[cluster_endpoint])
producer.send('my-topic-name', "test message")
```

But at this point I receive

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 576, in send
    self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 703, in _wait_on_metadata
    "Failed to update metadata after %.1f secs." % (max_wait,))
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
```

I've noticed that usually the port is `9091` or `9092` but when I go to "View client information" for my cluster my endpoint is as I wrote in my code with `9098` port number.

I tied to follow different advises here but nothing had helped.
This is what I've tried:

- [KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198606/kafkatimeouterror-failed-to-update-metadata-after-60-0-secs)
- [KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 300.0 secs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717319/kafkatimeouterror-kafkatimeouterror-failed-to-update-metadata-after-300-0-secs)
- https://community.bitnami.com/t/kafka-producer-timeoutexception-failed-to-update-metadata-after-60000-ms/82159/6

What am I missing?

Comment: What other properties are in your config file mentioned in the MSK link? For example, SSL requires certificates, and your Python code doesn't seem to be using any, therefore it will fail to authenticate and "timeout"

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm not sure that I have any SSL certifications.
I've tried to add ```listeners``` and ```advertised.listeners``` but it doesn't seem to be working. 

Here are some of my ```servers.properties```:

```listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9098```
```advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://boot-name.c1.kafka-serverless.reagion-name.amazonaws.com:9098
advertised.host.name=boot-name.c1.kafka-serverless.reagion-name.amazonaws.com:9098```

Comment: how did you finally fix it?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma I didn't. I created a MSK cluster instead of MSK Serverless and managed to set it up there with SSL configurations

Comment: I have a MSK cluster and the only configuration I've done is to autocreatetopics, do I need to configure something additional?

Comment: @YashKumarVerma I had to add permissions to the specific topic for the user that I was using to be able to produce and consume data from this topic

Comment: what does a user mean here?